# Mysql - How to get users who booked a certain number of days in a row?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table (tbl_reservations) with the following columns:

```
p_id
userid
reservation_id
book_date
db_add_date

p_id    userid  reservation_id  book_date       
1       01      124534          2016-02-19      2016-02-19
2       01      124554          2016-02-20      2016-02-20
3       01      124564          2016-02-21      2016-02-21
4       01      167823          2016-02-22      2016-02-22
5       01      12313           2016-02-23      2016-02-23
6       02      134564          2016-02-21      2016-02-21
7       03      197823          2016-02-22      2016-02-22
8       02      13313           2016-02-23      2016-02-23

**Desired Result**

As userid 01 booked reservation since last 5 days regularty it will appear in query result

userid
01
```

I want to get users who booked a certain number of days in a row ?

**e.g. I want to get unique users who booked in last 5 days**

Can anyone help me how to build a query for this? It would be a really big help. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, you seem to have different questions that are not equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

If you want unique users who booked in the last five days, then a query like this would seem to do what you want:

```
select userid
from tbl_reservations
where bookdate > date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 day) and bookdate <= curdate()
group by userid;
```

If you want users who booked on all the days:

```
select userid
from tbl_reservations
where bookdate > date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 day) and bookdate <= curdate()
group by userid
having count(*) = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT userid
from tbl_reservations
WHERE book_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND book_date <= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

Comment: The OP asked "I want to get users who booked a certain number of days in a row ?". As far as I understand, you are just getting anyone who has booked in the last 5 days

Comment: @Henders made changes,  added group by clause

Comment: But which part of your SQL means that every user you return has booked every single 'x' number of days? 

Unless i'm mistaken, the above still returns any user who has booked in the last 5 days regardless of the number of times they have booked.

Answer (score 0):

try this sql.You get Last % days who booked list from current date

```
select count(userid), userid
from tbl_reservations
where (book_date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY) and      book_date<=CURDATE())
group by userid
having count(*) = 5;
```